# Get id of selected Lookup Item

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I'm building a Visualforce page in which a form needs to be filled in. In the form there is a Lookup field to lookup an Account. After you've done this an AJAX calls should be done to update something else. The id of the selected item must be passed to this JS function.

The code for the `inputField` looks like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Account}" id="acct" onchange="doSomething(this.value);" />
```

So in the code above, `doSomething()` must get the id as an argument. In the current form, `this.value` contains the name of the selected item. Can I get the id, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspect the generated markup with Firebug or similar tool. Each lookup field consists of several input fields (one is visible, rest is hidden).

[image: example]

(in my example I've explicitly put `id` attribute on all tags from the top (apex:page, form block, section and finally the input field. If you don't do it you'll get autogenerated names).

So what you need to do:

1. from `this` go to parent tag (`this.parentNode` should work in plain DOM, of course [jQuery is always advised ;)](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif))
2. And get the child input field with Id ending with `acct_lkold`

Probably "[previousSibling](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_previoussibling.asp)" will work too?

Comment: Okay, I found out now through different channels that workarounds like this are indeed the only way to do it. I have implemented something like this now (slightly different, but the same idea).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```salesforce
<script>
function doThis(obj)
{
    alert(obj.id);
}
</script>

<apex:form>
    <apex:inputField value="{!acc.name}" id="myID" onchange="doThis(this);"/>
</apex:form>
```

If You need the selected object id - use actionSupport:

```salesforce
<script>
function doThis(param)
{
    alert(param);
}
</script>

<apex:inputField value="{!MyObject__c.AnotherObject__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"
                        oncomplete="doThis('{!MyObject__c.AnotherObject__c}');"
                        reRender="none"/>
</apex:inputField>
```

And finally if you can not (!) use actionSupport - use actionFunction instead:

```salesforce
<script>
function doThis(param)
{
    alert(param);
}
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="preSend"
                     oncomplete="doThis('{!MyObject__c.AnotherObject__c}');"
                     reRender="none"/>

<apex:inputField value="{!MyObject__c.AnotherObject__c}" onchange="preSend()"/>
```

Comment: I think this will get the id of the input element, not the id of the selected object.

Comment: The second option may work, but there was some reason (I can't remember it) that we couldn't use actionSupport... But it is a good option.

Comment: You can use actionFunction instead